# Disabling "use frame rate" slows logic/animation/etc?

Tags: python, game-engine, logic-bricks

I've recently solved an issue to remove my frame-rate cap, but it caused another issue. I have my animation tic rate at 60, my framerate at 60, and that's always been working *only* when I have "use frame rate" enabled. This option can be found here: Render > System. When disabled, I can go above 60 framerate which is ideal and it fixes other issues but my animation and logic are slowed down. I tried increasing/decreasing my animation frame rate and world FPS separately and together, but I can't get anywhere with it. How can I keep my animation framerate and world FPS at what it was *before* disabling "use frame rate"? Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT**: It comes out, "use frame rate" allows you to surpass the cap of 60, but **the game will run as fast as your framtime**. In other words, if you are running the game at 10 frametime, everything will be *running at 10 frames*, but if you are running at 300 frames, *everything will be running at 300 frames*. Higher frametime means higher animation and logic speed. To sum it up, "use frame rate" disables the cap but changes animation/logic fps to whatever you are running. As a solution, I am looking for a way to *only* surpass 60 framtime freely without any other changes. In other words, we need an alternative solution from "use frame rate", an alternative that *only* removes the 60 frametime cap and no other changes.

Comment: are you going to join [BGMC](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?383214-BGMC-18-THEME-ANNOUNCED!-%2817th-24th-October%29) this time around? you should. :P

Comment: @Vincent Scalia ;( Unfortunately, I wont.

Comment: :(... so far as your question goes, i don't know if that’s possible, since changing the frame-rate makes your problem, which makes you want to change the framerate... ect...ect..

Comment: @Vincent Scalia I have *not* changed any of the world framerate or animation framerate across *any* of my scenes, I simply disabled "use frame rate." It seems that it does just more than its name.

Comment: ah. so the problem is you want to apply it to animation but not the logic?

Comment: @Vincent Scalia disabling it should just let you exceed 60fps. Keep in mind that this is *not* world fps or animation fps, but **frametime, i.e. how fast you can run the game**. In other words, I just want to be able to exceed 60 frametime so the game runs as smoothly as it can rather than a cap. However, by doing this, I am creating another problem - the question above.

Comment: Disabling "use frame rate" disables the logic to run at constant speed.The consequence is that the speed of logic (behavior) now depends on how fast the BGE can process a certain frame. E.g. counting will not be uniform. That is why I recommend to avoid that setup. (You could increase the frame rate, but disabling is no good way).

Comment: @Monster and how would I do that?

Comment: Unfortunately It seams the frame rate parameter will be capped at 60fps (I never played with that parameter to increase it). - sorry